# Join two tables without common column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two SQL tables:

USPricing (ProductId, ProductTitle,Currency, Market, UnitPrice): contains price only in USD

```
1, 'Laptop', 'USD', 'US', 500
2, 'Computer', 'USD', 'US', 300
```

ExhangeRate (CurrencyCode, USDPerUnit): contains the conversion rate and the currency

```
INR, 0.01208
EUR, 1.0541
```

There is no common column between the two tables.
I want to come up with the SQL query to answer questions like:
**Find the laptop price in INR**

I'm using SQL server. Can someone help me with the query?

Expected Output:

```
Product, USD, INR
Laptop, 500, 41666 (500/0.0120)
```

Comment: Just use a sub-query to get the exchange rate for the currency requested... no need for a join.

Comment: You don't want it in your where clause? You want it as a calculated column.

Comment: I want it in where clause

Comment: Thats not required for "Find the laptop price in INR" - so maybe you can clarify what you are trying to do? Showing your actual desired results would help.

Comment: updated the question with expected output

Comment: And does your exchange rate seriously not store the date its valid? Thats the normal way you handle exchange rates.

Comment: And if this "Find the laptop price in INR" is your question, why does your desired results also contain USD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you can try as below.

```
select 
    ProductTitle as Product,
    UnitPrice as USD,
    (UnitPrice / (select USDPerUnit from ExchangeRate where Currencycode = 'INR')) as INR 
from USPricing
where ProductTitle ='Laptop'
```

---

The part of

```
select USDPerUnit from ExchangeRate where Currencycode = 'INR'
```

is for extracting the INR exchange rate as a number only.
And it will return:

| - | USDPerUnit |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.01208 |

Then, you can simply select the UnitPrice and multiply the result above.

---

If you want to make the script more readable or reusable,
you can also store the result of INR Exchange Rate as a var.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a subquery to get the exchange rate you want and calculate it in a new column

```
create table products (
  name varchar(255),
  currency char(3),
  country varchar(255),
  price decimal(19,2)
);    

insert into products (name, currency, country, price)
values
('Laptop', 'USD', 'US', 500),
('Computer', 'USD', 'US', 300);

create table rates(currency char(3), rate decimal(19,5));

insert into rates (currency, rate)
values
("INR", 0.01208),
("EUR", 1.0541);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select p.name, p.price as USD, (
        select round(p.price/r.rate, 2)
        from rates r
        where r.currency="INR"
    ) as INR
from products p;
```

| name | USD | INR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Laptop | 500 | 41390.73 |
| Computer | 300 | 24834.44 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aBTPb2gFybNFiyjES3PJ69/1)

Comment: Best practice is to **always** list the columns you are inserting into - I have edited your answer as we want people new to SQL to be aware of best practices. Currency hardly needs to be `varchar(255)` either.

Comment: Note to OP **DO NOT** use float for anything except scientific data. Never money or rates.

Comment: true, was just doing this on the fly, thanks for the edit

Comment: `"INR"`, for `SQL Server` which OP is using, string literal is single quote not double quote

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a CROSS JOIN:

```
select 
     I.ProductTitle as Product
   , I.UnitPrice as USD
   , I.UnitPrice/ER.Rate as INR
from 
    USPricing I
    cross join
    ExhangeRate ER
where ER.ccy='INR'
```

This join, with the WHERE condition here, joins every row in the USPricing table with the INR row from ExchangeRate.